# Converting private, dynamic type from interface{}

Tags: go, type-conversion, type-alias

I'm trying to test around an SQL query wherein one of the arguments is a `gosnowflake.Array` (essentially a wrapper to a slice) using the `go-sqlmock` package. Normally, something like this requires me to create a value converter, which I have included:

```
func (opt arrayConverterOption[T]) ConvertValue(v any) (driver.Value, error) {
    casted, ok := v.(*[]T)
    if ok {
        Expect(*casted).Should(HaveLen(len(opt.Expected)))
        for i, c := range *casted {
            Expect(c).Should(Equal(opt.Expected[i]))
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Type: %T\n", v)
        return v, nil
    }

    return "TEST_RESULT", nil
}
```

Now, this function is called for every argument submitted to the query. I use it to test the correctness of the values in the slice or pass the argument through if it isn't one. The problem I'm having is that, when I create a `arrayConverterOption[string]` and give it a `gosnowflake.Array(["A", "B", "C"])` as an argument, the type assertion fails because `gosnowflake.Array` returns an internal dynamic type, `*stringArray`, which is defined as a `*[]string`.

So you can see my dilemma here. On the one hand, I can't convert `v` because it's an `interface{}` and I can't alias `v` because the inner type is not `*[]string`, but `*stringArray`. So then, what should I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do this without resulting to reflection. However, with reflction I did manage it:

```
var casted []T
var ok bool

value := reflect.ValueOf(v)
if value.Kind() == reflect.Pointer {
    if inner := value.Elem(); inner.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        r := inner.Convert(reflect.TypeOf([]T{})).Interface()
        casted, ok = r.([]T)
    }
}
```

So, this code checks specifically for anything that is a pointer to a slice, which my dynamic type is. Then it uses reflection to convert the inner object to the slice type I was expecting. After that, I call `Interface()` on the result to get the `interface{}` from the reflected value and then cast it to a `[]T`. This succeeds. If it doesn't then I'm not working with one of those dynamically typed slices and I can handle the type normally.